# How to format different types of dates into one?

Tags: php, date

I have a `$birthday` that i taken from the database and it shows sometimes `1.12` (DAY.MONTH - without zeros in numbers and without a year) and sometimes as `1.12.1999` (DAY.MONTH.YEAR - without zeros in numbers and with a year)

i need to get a final result for a `$birthday` as `1.12` (DAY.MONTH - without zeros) and compare it to the current date (CURRENT_DAY.CURRENT_MONTH - without zeros) `$today = date("j.n");`

`if ($birthday == $today ) { echo 'Today is your birthday"; }else{ echo 'Today is not your birthday"; }`

How can i do it, how can i format it correctly , because i have different `$birthday` outputs each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
<?php
$pieces = explode(".", $birthday);
$day = ltrim($pieces[0], '0');
$month = ltrim($pieces[1], '0');
$birthday = $day . "." . $month;
?>
```

That should give you same format birthday each time without the year and without the leading zeros. Even if input is with or without zeros and with or without a year.

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out some patterns in the date strings. From the two data points that you've mentioned, I can see one common pattern in the `1.12` and `1.12.1999` date strings which is they both start with `day.month`. So, if this pattern is held true for all your cases, what simply can be done is to take the first two components of the date string,

```php
$today = date("j.n");
$dateStr = '1.12.1999'; // or 1.12
preg_match('/\d+\.\d+/', $dateStr, $matches);
$isBirthdayToday = isset($matches[0]) && $matches[0] === $today;
```

I hope this helps.